# How to compile thymeleaf/jsp in java code?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf, template-engine

I have property file with content:

```
INVALID_ARGUMENT=Field ${key} is invalid or missing.
```

In java code I have varibale `invalidArgument` which reads content of property file thus it contains:

```
Field ${key} is invalid or missing.
```

I want to write method which will replace `${key}` with my argument.

```
public void String(String input, String keyValue){
    ///please provide code to write here
}
```

I use spring boot and I use ThymeLeaf on FE thus it will be better to use thymeleaf.

Comment: why you don't use SpEL? I think Thymeleaf is overpowered for this use case.

Comment: @benkuly because I don't know how

Comment: You can also use String's replace(...) method...

Comment: Did any of this helped?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way:

```
public String paseKey(String input, String keyValue){
    return input.replace("${key}", keyValue);
}
```